# How to send email to people from choice column with multiple selections

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, column, email

I would like to choice people from choice column with multiple selections and then send email to these people by using workflow SPD.

Can I do it?

I use SharePoint Foundation

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796875/sharepoint-send-an-email-to-users-specified-in-a-field) by "Mayo"

> I have limited experience with SP Designer workflows, but have you
>   tried the email action with "Workflow Lookup" selected in the To
>   field? This allows you to use specific fields from the submitted list
>   item.

Comment: Regarding the edit: I am only familiar with the "Code" form of indenting, what type of indenting is this and how do I use it?